# Where do I put classes in Symfony that are neither Controllers nor models?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony

For my application bundle, I will need some classes that are neither controllers nor models. For instance, I would like to have a `scorecard` class that has members such as "skill", "efficiency", "beauty", etc. Also, it may have member method/getters like "meanScore".

Where would such a class go in the Symfony framework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with @Gordon that this sounds like a business object. But if you're sure that it isn't, your next step is to figure out how you would classify it. Is it a helper? An event listener? A utility class? Once you figure that out, ask yourself: is it specific to a bundle, or are you going to reuse it amongst projects?

Let's say you decide it's an event listener and belongs to the bundle. Put it in `MyBundle/EventListener`. If it's a helper, put it in `MyBundle/Helper`. Now if you plan on reusing it amonst projects (which in this case it actually doesn't sound like it, but bear with me...) you might be better off creating a place in `vendor` for it.

The important thing to remember is that because Symfony2 is so young, there isn't really a definitive list of best practices that answer questions like these. Right now it's kind of up to us to see what works, and what doesn't. It's like the wild west :)

Answer (score 3):

The way I answer these sorts of questions for myself is I go to [KnpBundles](http://knpbundles.com/) and check how other developers are doing it.

Another thing to note is that Symfony2 is all about freedom of choice when it comes to configuration. You can stick everything in `Random` folder for all Symfony2 kernel cares, as long as you set it up correctly. Well, that's probably taking it a bit to the extreme, but for example `Listener` or `EventListener` - no difference.

Now, if you'd ask me, I'd say that for the `Scorecard` - depending on where you're going to use it, either `Service` or `Helper/Util`

About the `breadcrumb` - seems like a good example for a twig extension.

Comment: I dont think it is a Service. Services usually do computations by calling on the public API of Domain objects. They rarely encapsulate their own state ("skill", "efficiency", "beauty"). They are more like a thin mediator layer between an outer layer like UI and the Domain layer.

Answer (score 2):

Since this class apparently represents a business object from your Domain, it belongs to the Model.

Comment: What about in the case where it is not a business object. Say I have the 'breadcrumb' class, with two members 'name' and 'href'?

Comment: @Robert I dont know where Symfony and Twig would put that. I'd still put it into the model, though not inside the Domain layer, but the general application layer because it's part of the UI. Or, if its reusable, I'd put it into some sort of framework/lib folder