# Symfony2 re-usable snippet functions

Tags: php, function, symfony, service, helper

I am using Symfony2 lately and I keep wondering when I should create a service and when I should create a class.

For example I do have this little snippet function that is a very reusable piece of code. So because of that I do not want that piece of code in my controller. Meaning that I would want to use it anywhere in my bundle.

It's very simple, but it basically generates a full url for me based on a slug/path. Now please note that this could be anything else for example a customStringGenerator() or what so ever.

The snippet:

```
public function generateUrlFromPath(Request $request, $path)
{
    return $request->getScheme() . '://' . $request->getHttpHost() . $request->getBasePath() . $path;
}
```

Now I could make some sort of Toolkit or UrlHelper class and define it as a service so I can easily inject the Request object, but it seems overdone for me to create a service for such a simple method.

What would anyone suggest in this case? What would you guys do when you have created reusable functions?

Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: For me, in this case, extending the `Request` symfony service is a better option as it only relies on the `Request` object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823294/extending-symfony-2-request-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reusability, I use:

- Services (When I need to inject other dependencies through constructor), so you don't have to do it manually everytime.
- Helper controller, which my controllers extend.
- Classes with public static functions.
- Traits (PHP >= 5.4), when you need to share same methods in a few classes, to help overcome single class inheritance limitation.

For your function up there, I would personally make a protected function inside a Helper controller, but a service would be ok too, even it is such a small piece of code. You might end up writing more code to that service later.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Utility class or even a Utility Bundle with your reusable codes. 
See the following links with instructions:
- [Symfony 2 - Where should I put a utility class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999806/symfony-2-where-should-i-put-a-utility-class)
- [Where do I put classes in Symfony that are neither Controllers nor models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326819/where-do-i-put-classes-in-symfony-that-are-neither-controllers-nor-models)

Depending on your case, you can add a 'Helper' subfolder (another namespace) to your bundle and use its methods from there. This is of course if you only plan to re-use that code from inside that Bundle.